# How to show the three months calendar of non-Gregorian calendars?

Tags: calendar

Running `M-x calendar` shows three months calendar of Gregorian
calendar like below:

[image]

Emacs has also other calendars (Chinese, Hebrew, Julian, Mayan,
... ). How to show the three month calendar of these calendars like
Gregorian?

For example for the `French year` (just for example) I mean an output like below (which I created it by hand): Emacs know the names of Months of French year, I only written the abbreviation of the days of the week. Actually when the point is at today (e.g. 17 July 2015), running `M-x calendar-french-print-date` gives `French Revolutionary date: 29 Messidor an 223 de la Révolution`.

[image]

**Edit:** actually the month Messidor has only 30 days based on Emacs.

Comment: Emacs shows the traditional calendar with 365 days and 12 months, which permits showing holidays and special events based on the other calendars you mentioned.  The built-in calendar library does not (that I am aware of) show a calendar containing a different number of days/months.  Is your question how to show the holidays and special events based on other calendars, or, are you asking how to show something other than 365 days / 12 months?

Comment: @lawlist I updated the question.

Comment: It looks like you probably want to modify `calendar-generate-month`.  The library `cal-french.el` has functions that look like they can *perhaps* be substituted -- e.g., `calendar-french-last-day-of-month`.  Perhaps it won't be that difficult to convert `calendar-generate-month` to your own needs, but then you'll need to modify moving point functions and so forth to the right date to place your overlays for holidays and meetings and to extract the correct French date.